# Dislike track or playlist recommendation

Tags: itunes, apple-music

On iOS I have the option to tell Apple Music that I don't like this recommendation. In iTunes this functionality doesn't seem to be present. Is this indeed not possible within iTunes or am I missing something?

[image: I do not like this suggestion -- music app iOS 8.4]

Comment: Where are you seeing this don't like option?

Comment: @unknowndomain tapping and holding on a suggestion on the for you section opens up a menu that offers the "dislike" option.